# Xcode UItableviewCell with dynamic height, the first THREE cells have a width around the image but after reuse is called its fixed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

So i have finally got my dynamic cells with imageviews working, the only problem im running into now is that the first THREE cells or two depending on how large the image content may be are not updating to the corrected constraint. Even after using tableview.beginupdates and endupdates it will not update until REUSE.

I was using Cache for cell height, but I opted out for an automatic dimension.

Here is how the first THREE images look inside the tableview.

all my other cells load exactly like the second image provided. only the first three are messed up, any ideas would be appreciated.

[Images with width problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm5FR.jpg)

[Images right after Reuse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsIz4.jpg)

```
EDIT
```

My cell is almost an exact copy of Instagram's homepage cells. I have an imageview with a UIview to hold video layers, it all now is automatic sizing perfectly no matter the media type nor the size. I figured it would be easier to do this client-side instead of server-side.

if anyone needs help or running into similar issues MAKE SURE to check constraints and make sure you set proper values. EVERYTHING has to be dead on

Answer (score 1):

Okay so i provided myself with a little bit of a hack but it does work while keeping the smoothfeel of the tableview right after it has passed the 3rd index row, if anyone knows anything about the similar situation this is how i managed to fix it.

agian it is hacky so keep that in mind.

This is inside the async method for image retrieval. I am using math to figure out the asset images size and width and providing a height constraint for the imageview based on that.

If you have images/videos with dynamic sizing this will also fix the first 3 cells for the videos as well.

```
if indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 2{
            
            UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.endUpdates()

            }
            
        }
```